# how to break color using css

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">
.list .name{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
.items .name{
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class="list">
    <div class="name">Products</div>
    <div class="items"> 
        <div class="name">Product Name</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

In the above code, class ".list .name". the "name" is bold and color is red.
And ".items .name" is without bold and color.

What I need is, I don't need to overflow the ".list .name" color and bold to the class ".items .name". I want to break the 1st class in the beginning of ".items"

I need to use "name" in both div.

Comment: You mean you want to make the `.items .name` bold and red? Wouldn't replacing `.list .name` by just `.name` in the CSS achieve that?

Also you might be looking for the `>` separator -- `.foo .bar` matches any descendant element, with a class `bar`, with an ancestor with a class of `foo`. `.foo > .bar`, however, only matches a child with a class `bar`, of a parent with a class `foo`. You may be looking, specifically, for `.list > .name` in the first CSS selector.

Comment: Are you really trying to use `clear: both` to remove `font-weight:bold` and `color:red`?

Answer (score 1):

`clear: both` is nothing to do with removing earlier styles. Just use the inherit value on all the properties you change:

```
.list .name {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
.list .items .name{
    font-weight: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP _doesn't_ want to apply color/bold to the `.items .name` I think as @Federico mentioned, the OP is probably looking for `>` separator

Comment: Wouldn't that just make the second "name" div inherit from "items", which isn't set?

Comment: @Fantabulum: most CSS properties default to "inherit". That's why they're **cascading** style sheets.

Comment: @Eric: I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  We had different interpretations as to what the OP wants.

Comment: @Fantabulum: My answer has the same effect as @Nupul's ` `

Comment: @Eric: Sorry my bad :) overlooked that

Answer (score 1):

```
.list > .name {

font-weight:bold;
    color:red;

}
```

Should do the trick